# How to reverse-construct confusion matrix form evaluation metrics values?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, reverse-engineering, confusion-matrix

We get statistics of evaluation metrics (like precision, recall, accuracy, etc.) from the confusion matrix.

Is there any way to reverse the process?

In a binary classification problem, I have results of the evaluation metrics: Precision, Recall, F1-Measure, Accuracy, Specificity, and Balanced Accuracy. I want to reverse construct confusion matrix using them.

Is there any reverse derivation for getting values for `TN, FP, FN, TP?`

Answer (score 0):

Since all these metrics are ratios, its unlikely you will be able to determine the original size of the data, if it not known. All the values will be relative to the size of the data.

```
p = TP / (TP + FP) => FP = p' * TP (Precision)
r = TP / (FN + TP) => FN = r' * TP (Recall)
s = TN / (TN + FP) => FP = s' * TN (Specifity)

where
  p' = (1-p)/p, s' = (1-s)/s, r' = (1-r)/r

Size = TP + FP + FN + TN =>
Size = TP + p' TP + r' TP + 1/s' FP =>
Size = (1+p'+r'+p'/s')FP
```

And the rest of wanted values can be easily calculated from the above equations.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I realise that this question is over a year old, I had a similar problem yesterday where I needed to know if certain metrics are achievable.

Google searches for this problem *only* show this question, so I decided to solve it and share it here in case anyone in the future requires a solution.

My solution is too long to post as code here, but I have made a project which will extract all of the possible confusion matrices for a given dataset size against certain metrics.

Here is the link to my repository housing the project:

[Sam-Pewton/reverse_engineer_confusion_matrix](https://github.com/Sam-Pewton/reverse_engineer_confusion_matrix)

The code will extract all possible confusion matrices for given parameters and dump all outputs to a .csv file.

As eluded to by UziGoozie, you **need** to know the size of each of the classes for this problem - it would be impossible without. As a bare minimum my project requires the sizes of both classes, the number of decimal places to round your metrics to, and the accuracy you are trying to prove.

Other optional metrics I have included to filter by are:

- Sensitivity (Recall/TPR)
- Specificity (TNR)
- F1 Score
- Precision

Explaination on how to use the code is all documented in the projects README.

I hope this helps.